# Stop laptop bios beeping [NO DISPLAY]

Tags: laptop, display, motherboard, bios, sound-card

So, I've an old Dell Inspiron 15R which I would love to rescue, the thing is the screen doesn't work, everything else is fine, and I can use it perfectly with an external screen, the thing is the motherboard wont stop beeping just warning me the display isn't detected, but I don't want to fix it, I'm fine using a monitor.

Is there a way, I can stop the beeping, or some workaround for that, its really annoying.